# Insert random value in another random value, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, random

Let me begin by telling you that I'm new to working with jQuery and haven't got that much programming experience in general. This is my first attempt to actually try to learn this, and therefore I'd appreciate to keep explanations and solutions pretty basic if possible.

I'm working on generating a complete block of text from random sentences. This works fine. However I'd like to be able to insert random value into another for more "dynamic randomness". For example I'd like to make use of random names inside other random variables.

For example I'd like to create from the array `var Malsattning` an output that read:
'The vision is for [insert Name from `Var Foretagsnamn`] to create a positive attitude towards the brand' I also want to keep the ability generate a Name from `Var Foretagsnamn` by itself (as with all current generated words/sentences).

It's kind of difficult to explain, so I created a jsFiddle for you to look into if the code below won't suffice; http://jsfiddle.net/lennyekberg/gFUxG/

```
/////////////////////////////
//   Foretagsnamn (Name)   //
/////////////////////////////
    var Foretagsnamn = [
    'Lisa',
    'Ann',
    'Matt',
    'Carl',
    'Sara',
    'Ron'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxForetagsnamn = Foretagsnamn.length;

// get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomForetagsnamn() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxForetagsnamn = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxForetagsnamn));
    //return the random sentence
    return Foretagsnamn[rndIdxForetagsnamn];                        
}

//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
function showRandomForetagsnamn(selector){
  var randomForetagsnamn = getRandomForetagsnamn();  
  $(selector).html(randomForetagsnamn);
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Foretagsbeskrivning (Workdescription)   //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////


var Foretagsbeskrivning = [
    'is an icecream vendor',
    'is a plumber',
    'organizes charity events',
    'build hybrid cars'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxForetagsbeskrivning = Foretagsbeskrivning.length;  

//get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomForetagsbeskrivning() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxForetagsbeskrivning = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxForetagsbeskrivning));
    //return the random sentence
    return Foretagsbeskrivning[rndIdxForetagsbeskrivning];                        
}


//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
    //vad är en DOM selector, för alla taggar i html eller?
function showRandomForetagsbeskrivning(selector){
  var randomForetagsbeskrivning = getRandomForetagsbeskrivning();  
  $(selector).html(randomForetagsbeskrivning);
}


////////////////////////////
//   Målsättning (Goal)   //
////////////////////////////


var Malsattning = [
    'The vision is to dominate the market in three years',
    'The vision is to create a positive attitude towards the brand',
    'The goal is to create a huge profit in the next two years',
    'Ett mål för det fortsatta arbetet är att kunna hävda sig mot konkurrenter och skeptiker'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxMalsattning = Malsattning.length;  

//get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomMalsattning() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxMalsattning = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxMalsattning));
    //return the random sentence
    return Malsattning[rndIdxMalsattning];                        
}


//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
    //vad är en DOM selector, för alla taggar i html eller?
function showRandomMalsattning(selector){
  var randomMalsattning = getRandomMalsattning();  
  $(selector).html(randomMalsattning);

}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Målsättning, genomförande (Goal, execution)  //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


var Malsattninggenomforande = [
    'with the implementation of sustainable solutions',
    'by using viral marketing',
    'by creating new demands on the market',
    'with a nation wide marketing campaign'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxMalsattninggenomforande = Malsattninggenomforande.length;  

//get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomMalsattninggenomforande() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxMalsattninggenomforande = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxMalsattninggenomforande));
    //return the random sentence
    return Malsattninggenomforande[rndIdxMalsattninggenomforande];                        
}


//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
    //vad är en DOM selector, för alla taggar i html eller?
function showRandomMalsattninggenomforande(selector){
  var randomMalsattninggenomforande = getRandomMalsattninggenomforande();  
  $(selector).html(randomMalsattninggenomforande);

}



/////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Målsättning, resultat (Goal, result)  //
/////////////////////////////////////////////


var MalsattningResultat = [
    'which will result in new buisness opportunities',
    'and in time reach a wider audience',
    'that will create a positive attitude to the business'
    ],
    //the current sentences length
    maxMalsattningResultat = MalsattningResultat.length;  

//get and return a random sentences from array
function getRandomMalsattningResultat() {
    //calculate a random index
    var rndIdxMalsattningResultat = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxMalsattningResultat));
    //return the random sentence
    return MalsattningResultat[rndIdxMalsattningResultat];                        
}


//show a random sentences in a DOM selector
    //vad är en DOM selector, för alla taggar i html eller?
function showRandomMalsattningResultat(selector){
  var randomMalsattningResultat = getRandomMalsattningResultat();  
  $(selector).html(randomMalsattningResultat);

}



//////////////////
//    Output    //
//////////////////


//used to output the different sentences
//used by .click & .ready beneath
var outputLista = function() {
    showRandomForetagsnamn(".foretagsnamn");
    showRandomForetagsbeskrivning(".foretagsbeskrivning");
    showRandomMalsattning(".malsattning");
    showRandomMalsattninggenomforande(".malsattninggenomforande");                   
    showRandomMalsattningResultat(".malsattningresultat");
   }


$('.rndButton').click(function(e){
    outputLista();
    console.log('get random sentences at click...');
});

//generates random sentences when the page loads
$('.rndButton').ready(function(e){
    console.log('get random sentences at page load...');
    outputLista();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be the use of placeholders.
If you change e.g.

```
'The vision is to dominate the market in three years'
```

to

```
'The vision is for @@person@@ to dominate the market in three years'
```

you could then do something like

```
var randomName = getRandomForetagsnamn();
var randomMalsattning = getRandomMalsattning();
var result = randomMalsattning.replace('@@person@@', randomName);
alert(result);
```

You just need to ensure that the placeholder is something that occurs nowhere else in the text - easily achievable if you use special characters to pad the placeholder.

**EDIT**: I've created a very basic JSFiddle for demonstration purposes: http://jsfiddle.net/8YjVc/1/

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. [Made a quick jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lennyekberg/nLq6n/) if anyone else would like to take a look.
One thought for future use; is it possible to replace more than one word, like 
`var result = randomMalsattning.replace('@@person@@', randomName, @@car@@, randomCar);` ?

Comment: You can do `randomMalsattning.replace('@@person@@', randomName).replace('@@car@@', randomCar);`
Basically, the `replace` function will accept two parameters, the first one being a regular expression which can be a simple string, the second one being the value you want to replace the placeholder with.
The return value is also a string, so you can simply chain multiple calls to the replace function if you want to perform multiple replacements.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I meant. Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split fonction to put the name into the result. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gFUxG/8/) is the fiddle.

To use easily the split, create a var for the name outside of functions :

```
var name;
```

Then, change your results adding characters that you will split (here the characters are "[]") :

```
var Malsattning = [
    'The vision is for [] to dominate the market in three years',
    'The vision is for [] to create a positive attitude towards the brand',
    'The goal is for [] to create a huge profit in the next two years',
    'Ett mål för det fortsatta arbetet är att kunna hävda sig mot konkurrenter och skeptiker'
],
```

Finally, split and show the result :

```
function showRandomMalsattning(selector){
  var randomMalsattning = getRandomMalsattning();
    var split = randomMalsattning.split('[]');
  $(selector).html(split[0] + name + split[1]);
}
```

Comment: This solution works, as far as I can see, well - Except when '[]' isn't present in a sentence in the array. For example the fourth sentence in your example get "Carlundefined" or "Saraundefined" etc. written at the end of it, since it has not been split in the array. Is there a way to use sentences both with and without '[]' with this solution?